# Backlog / Complete log of gTalk conversation in Adium?

Tags: google-talk, adium

Any way to make adium fetch the complete conversation history for each open window?

Android and Gmail will both show you messages received while you were signed out, or signed into a different client. Adium only shows you messages received directly by the Adium client.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Google is using a custom XMPP extension for this feature, which is not documented or reverse engineered.

There are two extensions that could be used for this:

- http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html
- http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html

However, these are still experimental and not supported by Google Talk or Adium.